# Parameter since in pouchdb sync doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I use PouchDB in a web/mobile application that performs replication from a CouchDB database, and then I activate the synchronization provided by PouchDB. This synchronization, under the hood, performs bidirectional replication and triggers whenever a change occurs.

When you exit the application and re-enter, the synchronization is triggered to check for any changes that have occurred. The PouchDB synchronization method allows you to pass a parameter called "since" with a token that identifies the last change that has occurred in the CouchDB database. Alternatively, you can pass "now" to the "since" parameter to synchronize changes from that point onward, or you can omit the parameter.

The issue I'm facing is that when I pass the update_seq as the value for the since parameter, the synchronization stops working properly. Well, to be more accurate, it partially works. If I make changes in my application, they are not synchronized and remain only locally. However, if I make changes directly in CouchDB, those changes are synchronized with the application.

I hope you can help me with this issue.

Comment: I have been commenting this case in an issue from github and that  seem the problem is that since option in sync method set same value for pull and push replication therefore only one works. If you use sync the only valid values for since option are 0 (sync from the begining), now (sync from now) and not set (sync what is not sync).